# How to manage other option in any listing?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have one Category List user will select a category from the list if user didn't find a category in the list, then he will select "other" option and it will display a text box there user will enter a new category name. This newly added category will go for approval to Site Admin till then it should be mentioned as "Uncategorised". 
So my question is how to achieve this using a mysql table should I create a new table as uncategorized category or should I add one extra column to category table as "isApproved". As the solution should be for both add and edit of new category.

Answer (score 0):

As you described

> Admin must approve newly added category.

To acheive that you definitely will have a field `status` or something like that to check if this category is approved or not. You can simply use that field. If it is not **active**, it is "Uncategorized.

Comment: There may be a possibility after adding new category that when a user adds one category, e.g. "PHP" and it is sent for approval towards admin till then it will be uncategorized and one new user comes to the site and he also adds same new category "PHP" in this case how to manage edit of that category and should we send that category for approval also.

Answer (score 0):

A more flexible way than adding one `isApproved` (or rather a more generic name like `status`) column to your table is to create a whole new *temporary* table. There are number of reasons why this is the better approach:

- You can save diagnostical information like who created this category, when did he create it, and so on.
- You separate your logic: An unapproved entry is, simply put, a temporary one. Approving it is nothing more than moving it over to your categories table and thus making it permanent.
- Your categories table doesn't get clustered with unnecessary entries.

Comment: I think this may suit the situation can you please update your answer for the possibility of same category by two users.

Comment: What do you mean? For a table like `id`, `user_id`, `category_name`, `date`, ... every user can create a new category. Then It's up to you to approve them or not.

Comment: As every new category will go for Approval but here may be a possibility of that a user adds one category, e.g. "PHP" and it is sent for approval towards admin till then it will be uncategorized and another one user comes to the site and he also adds same new category "PHP" in this case how to manage edit of that category and should we send that category for approval also

Comment: If you approve a category, insert the name into the `categories` table and then just delete all temporary entries where the `category_name` is *PHP*.